# ChatterBot error loading 'en' model in spaCy: OSError [E941]

Tags: python, spacy, chatterbot

I am currently working on building a chatbot using Python 3.8 (64-bit) and have successfully installed Chatterbot using pip. However, when running my code, I encountered an error related to the 'en' model in spaCy. I have also installed spaCy using the command prompt in Windows 10.

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/chatt.py", line 12, in <module>
    chatbot = ChatBot('MyChatBot')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.storage = utils.initialize_class(storage_adapter, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\utils.py", line 33, in initialize_class
    return Class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Uer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\sql_storage.py", line 20, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\storage_adapter.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.tagger = Tagger(language=kwargs.get(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 54, in load
    return util.load_model(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 448, in load_model
    raise IOError(Errors.E941.format(name=name, full=OLD_MODEL_SHORTCUTS[name]))  # type: ignore[index]
OSError: [E941] Can't find model 'en'. It looks like you're trying to load a model from a shortcut, which is obsolete as of spaCy v3.0. To load the model, use its full name instead:

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

For more details on the available models, see the models directory: https://spacy.io/models. If you want to create a blank model, use spacy.blank: nlp = spacy.blank("en")
```

Code:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer


chatbot = ChatBot('MyChatBot')


trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)


trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english")


while True:
    user_input = input("You: ")
    response = chatbot.get_response(user_input)
    print("ChatBot:", response)
```

Additional Details:

-Python version: 3.8 (64-bit)
-Operating System: Windows 10
-spaCy version: 3.5.3
-ChatterBot version 1.1.0a7

I have tried various approaches, including changing Python versions to 3.7 and installing different versions of spaCy like 3.4.0, but I am still encountering the 'en' model not found error.

I would greatly appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance for your assistance.